# How to calculate the distance of two circles in a image by opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

image with two circles

[image]

I have an image that include two fibers (presenting as two circles in the image). How can I calculate the distance of two fibers?

I find it hard to detect the position of the fiber. I have tried to use the HoughCircles function, but the parameters are hard to optimize and it cannot locate the circle precisely in most times. Should I subtract the background first or is there any other methods? MANY Thanks!

Comment: _it cannot locate the circle precisely in most times_ are you analyzing a video or standalone images? And if so please link to them aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using hough circle detection but you should provide more images if you want a more stable detection. I just do denoising and go straight to circle detection. Using a non-local means denoising is pretty good at preserving edges which is in turn good for the canny edge algorithm included in the hough circle algorithm.

My code is written in Python but can easily be translated into C++.

```py
import cv2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

IM_PATH = 'your image path'
DS = 2 # downsample the image

orig = cv2.imread(IM_PATH, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
orig = cv2.resize(orig, (orig.shape[1] // DS, orig.shape[0] // DS))
img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(orig, h=3, templateWindowSize=20 // DS + 1, searchWindowSize=40 // DS + 1)

plt.imshow(orig, cmap='gray')
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=200 // DS, param1=40 // DS, param2=40 // DS, minRadius=210 // DS, maxRadius=270 // DS)

if circles is not None:
    for x, y, r in circles[0]:
        c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, fill=False, lw=1, ec='C1')
        plt.gca().add_patch(c)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((12, 8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Important

Doing a bit of image processing is only the first step in a good (and stable!) object detection. You have to leverage every detail and property that you can get your hands on and apply some statistics to improve your results. For example:

- Use [Yves' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749327/6205379) as an addition and filter all detected circles that do not intersect the joints.
- Is one circle always underneath the other? Filter out horizontally aligned pairs.
- Can you reduce the ROI (are the circles always in a specific area in your image or can they be everywhere)?
- Are both circles always the same size? Filter out pairs with different sizes.
- ...

If you can use multiple metrics you can apply a statistical model (ex. majority voting or knn) to find the best pair of circles.

Again: always think of what you know about your object, the environment and its behavior and take advantage of that knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you haven't shown your preprocessing steps. In my approach, I'll do the following:

1. Convert input image to grayscale (see [`cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab)).
2. Median blurring, maintains the "edges" (see [`medianBlur`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9)).
3. Adaptive thresholding (see [`adaptiveTreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3)).
4. Morphological opening to get rid of small noise (see [`morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f)).
5. Find circles by `HoughCircles`.
6. Not done here: Possible refinements of the found circles. Exclude too small or too large circles. Use all prior information you have on that! For example, how large can the circles be at all?

Here's my whole code:

```cpp
// Read image.
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("images/i7aJJ.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

// Convert to grayscale for processing.
cv::Mat blk;
cv::cvtColor(img, blk, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// Median blurring to improve following thresholding.
cv::medianBlur(blk, blk, 11);

// Adaptive thresholding.
cv::adaptiveThreshold(blk, blk, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 51, -2);

// Morphological opening to get rid of small noise.
cv::morphologyEx(blk, blk, cv::MORPH_OPEN, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(3, 3)));

// Find circles using Hough transform.
std::vector<cv::Vec4f> circles;
cv::HoughCircles(blk, circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.0, 300, 50, 25, 100);

// TODO: Refinement of found circles, if there are more than two.
// For example, calculate areas: Neglect too small or too large areas.
// Compare all areas, and keep the two with nearly matching areas and
// suitable areas.

// Draw circles in input image.
for (Vec4f& circle : circles) {
    cv::circle(img, cv::Point(circle[0], circle[1]), circle[2], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);
    cv::circle(img, cv::Point(circle[0], circle[1]), 5, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), cv::FILLED);
}

// --- Assuming there are only the two right circles left from here. --- //

// Draw some debug output in input image.
const cv::Point c1 = cv::Point(circles[0][0], circles[0][1]);
const cv::Point c2 = cv::Point(circles[1][0], circles[1][1]);
cv::line(img, c1, c2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

// Calculate distance, and put in input image.
double dist = cv::norm(c1 - c2);
cv::putText(img, std::to_string(dist), cv::Point((c1.x + c2.x) / 2 + 20, (c1.y + c2.y) / 2 + 20), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.0, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
```

The final output looks like this:

[image: Final output]

The intermediate image right before the `HoughCircles` operation looke like this:

[image: Intermediate image]

In general, I'm not that skeptical about `HoughCircles`. You "just" have to pay attention to your preprocessing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The circle fit is quite poor, especially at the bottom. This can only be used as a pre-measurement step.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Feel free to suggest possible improvements, and I'm more than happy to implement these in my answer. As is, your comment is not very helpful at all - sorry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I can't see, at which point I haven't accepted your criticism. I just asked for some more helpful information. In fact, the tone of _your_ initial comment was kind of snarky. And, together with your second comment, at least from my point of view, you reveal an actual inability to properly express your criticism. What a pity, but I guess not every high rep SO user can be role model. Thanks for the downvote AFTER I replied to your comment. Would've made more sense to downvote in first place, but what I do know about accepting criticism, right?